# caching using Javascript

Tags: javascript, caching

I am using IE 7.0. I want to clear the cache for every new request. So i need java script code  for clear the cache. In IE i am using one setting to fix the caching issues. This is location:
Tools-Internet Options-Browsing History Settings-Every time i visit the web page-Ok.
It works fine for the current IE browser. Now I need to implement this concept using Java script. Please suggest me.

```
Response.Buffer = False
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
```

I tried, but not working.

Comment: Do you control the requests to the JavaScript, like are they AJAX calls?

Comment: How come you are still using IE7? Microsoft stated that they would auto-upgrade users to IE8/IE9, depending on your operating system (reference: http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9222811/FAQ_Microsoft_s_new_IE_auto_upgrade_scheme_explained).

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** clear the cache using JavaScript. You can, however, trick the browser into thinking the page is different than what is stored in the cache by appending a number to the end of the URL.

So, for example, if you want to ensure that the browser is using your latest JS, append a number to the end of the source attribute (a different number will be needed each time you wish to "trick" the browser caching):

```
<script src="myScript.js?1" />
```

If you want to clear the cache for the entire page, you need to be asking a different question: How to control caching with [enter server-side language here]?

Note: Your new question, if needed, should be asked in a new question on SO.

Comment: You mean append a number that changes. Appending the same number all the time would be a fail ;)

Comment: @Lloyd, I thought it was obvious. I updated it for clarity. Thanks in advance for your upvote :P

Comment: But where i can found myScript.js file. Actually i did the IE setting then its works fine. But still issues.

Comment: Yeh it was to me, I knew what you meant but gotta be clear for others that's all.

Comment: @user1304807 How are you doing the requests? Are they static script inserts or something dynamic?

Comment: @user1304807, if you don't know how your JS files are being included in the page, I think you should start there.

Comment: It is dynamic request. For this i am using <script src="Scripts/custom_reorder.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: OK then, if you want to force a refresh of your JS, your code would be: `<script src="Scripts/custom_reorder.js?1" type="text/javascript"></script>`. Notice the `?1` at the end of your script?

Comment: Yea, I tried but still same issues. The Problem is that it is not showing Updated value. So when i clear the cache manually then it will shows the Updated Value. so now tell me your suggestion.

Comment: One more thing I am using JQuery for this. So when i click on button( Note: Here i am using html button) it will not Postback.

Comment: @user1304807, based on the information you've provided, I've helped as much as I can. I'm sorry...